# Entering UK on a business visa for vacation

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, business-travel

I applied for UK Standard Visitor visa a few months ago to attend my company's team building event in the London office. In my application I truthfully stated that it was for a business trip, and that my company sponsored it, but that I'd also like to stay there for another two weeks for vacation.

The plans fell through as I was unable to obtain my visa in time for the event. I did get the visa in the end, and it's still valid, can I use it to travel to UK for leisure purposes? What are the possible repercussions for travelling for a reason different from what I stated in the application?

Comment: Do you *personally* meet the visa eligibility requirements? A material change in the premise on which a visa was granted (such as changing from a business trip sponsored by your company with some tourism tacked on, to an unsponsored trip solely for tourism) could be grounds for denial of entry / cancellation of your visa on arrival at the border.

Comment: @Traveller to the best of my knowledge yes, I'm eligible for Standard Visitor visa, with or without company support

Comment: In that case, play safe - don’t risk a denial of entry, apply again in your own name

Comment: Meant to say, you can [get a refund](https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa/get-refund) of your original application fee if you’ve not yet given biometrics.

Comment: Why would they give you the business visa if it was too late for the event? And if you somehow obtained a visa for business reasons, but too late for the event, why do you expect to be admitted?

Comment: @Traveller I've submitted biometrics and received the visa months ago, so it's probably too late for that

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not sure I understand your question(s). "Why would they give you the business visa if it was too late for the event?" -- Well, they did. "Why do you expect to be admitted?" -- I _hope_ they'd let me in because my visa hasn't expired yet, and I did specify both leisure and business as the purpose of my trip. If I _expected_ that, I wouldn't be asking for advice?

Comment: @Nobody Your question implies you still haven’t got the visa *(“assuming I did get the visa in the end”)*.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is **no such thing** as a ‘UK business visa’. A UK *Standard Visitor visa* allows the holder to undertake certain [permitted activities](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-visitor-permitted-activities) as a visitor, of which general business activities (such as meetings, conferences) is a sub-set.

Second, when you applied for your visa, you did so on the basis of attending a team building event *sponsored by your company* with some personal tourism tacked on. You haven’t used the visa for its original stated purpose and now you want to use it solely for tourism. That’s potentially a material change in the premise on which the visa was granted which, IMHO, could be grounds for denial of entry / cancellation of your visa on arrival at the border.

If you’re confident you can prove to UK Border Control, if asked, that you still meet the [eligibility / suitability / genuine visitor requirements](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor) then go ahead and plan your trip. If not, apply for another visa.